# Number down a column based on amount of rows from another column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to number column A in increments by 1, based on how many rows are in column B [Example of my Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4dHu.png)

The code I currently have does this, but the top number does not end up being 1. I need to start with 1 at the top and count down.

```
Sub SecondsNumbering()

     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Formatted")
     Dim LastRow As Long
     Dim i As Long

     With ws
         LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

         For i = 6 To LastRow
             .Cells(i, 1).Value = i - 1
         Next
     End With

End Sub
```

With this, I am counting the number of rows in the column.

Edit: When I do the value 7 for i, so that it starts at 6 (which is where I want data to start) [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVXck.png) is what I get.

Comment: `i - 1` is equal to `5` on the first iteration... so should be pretty easy math to make it start at `1` right?

Comment: I thought the same thing, but when I change that combination of values to make it so that  it starts at 1, the value printed is not one.

Comment: What did you change it to?

Comment: Edited to show picture

Comment: `.Cells(i, 1).Value = i - 5`.

Comment: So that brings the 1 to the correct spot but then i have 5 blank spots at the bottom

Comment: I don't see how that's possible. The loop is *still* looping from `6` to `LastRow`... so it is writing in every single cell from row `6` to `LastRow` in column A.

Comment: Got it thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

   Dim lCntr As Long

   lCntr = 6

   Do
      If (Cells(lCntr, 2) <> "") Then Cells(lCntr, 1) = lCntr - 5
      lCntr = lCntr + 1
   Loop Until Cells(lCntr, 2) = ""

End Sub
```

[image]

HTH